# product which works like numpy.add.at

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have multiple counting indices as in the example here:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(3)
np.add.at(a, np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
```

This gives `array([2, 6, 16])` for `a`. Is there a way to do the same for a **product**? So something like `np.prod.at(a, ..., ...)`, which would return `array([1, 6, 120])`? It doesn't have to be numpy, but I need it for an intensive calculation, so I don't want to keep the numpy speed if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `np.multiply.at`, but the starting array should contain ones rather than zeros for obvious reasons:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(3)
np.multiply.at(a, np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
print(a)
# [  1.   6. 120.]
```